# AJAX mail sending

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send email via AJAX on button press:

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    $message = $_POST['msg'];

    mail("mymailbox@gmail.com", "subj!", $message);
}
?>
```

**JS:**

```
(function($) {
    $('.cart__item__send-order').click(function() {
        var data = '&msg=' + 'random text';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "order_mail.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(){
                console.log('email sent!');
            }
        });
    });
});
}(jQuery));
```

but nothing happens! Could you please help me to find out the reason it doesn't work?
btw, it consoles.log *'email sent!'*

Comment: Look in the browser's "net" tab what the PHP file responded. There may have been an error when you called `mail()`.

Comment: What does the log on your mail server say?

Comment: It's worth checking your spam folder in gmail as well, it will often be marked as spam.

Comment: >What does the log on your mail server say?

I can see the subj and the date of sending of some mails.

Answer (score 0):

Well there might be something wrong with the PHP side, but you are building the data string wrong.

```
var data = '&msg=' + 'random text';
```

needs to be

```
var data = 'msg=' + 'random text';
```

or

```
var data = { msg : 'random text' };
```

Comment: Thanks, I did the change, but still can't send the mail. I got "Status Code:200 OK" in the "Network" tab of the browser

Comment: Than you have a PHP issue. That I can not help with.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working in a own machine, you must have activated some application that let you connect to a smtp server, or you must be mount your own smtp server. If you don't know how do this, I recommend to you that use PHPMailer is a php class that let you connect, for example, to google smtp and send from there any mail

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

a comment, in the success function try

```
success: function(response){
console.log(response);
}
```

with this you confirm the response of your php code